# Update no Zend 2

Tags: php, sql, zend

Estou estudando o Zend Framework 2 e estou necessitando de uma mão para fazer um update em duas tabelas que estão  relacionadas. Vamos lá.

Tenho a **tabela entradas** com os campos:

```
id_entrada       id_notafiscal
```

e  na **tabela notafiscal** os campos:

```
id_notafiscal cod_notafiscal
```

Resumi a quantidade de campos para facilitar.

Preciso atualizar a tabela nota fiscal e até consigo utizando a query:

```sql
UPDATE notafiscal  en
INNER  JOIN entrada e   
ON e.id_notafiscal = en.id_notafiscal
and  id_entrada='2014-02-24'
SET cod_notafiscal=1
```

Como fazer isso utilizando Zend 2?

Para facilitar  um pouco mais vou postar o código que uso para fazer um select

entre várias tabelas.

```
public function find($id)
    {
        $id  = (int)$id;   
        $sql= $this->tableGateway->select(function (Select $select) use ($id) {
               $select->join('enotafiscal','entrada.id_notafiscal=enotafiscal.id_notafiscal','cod_notafiscal','left');
                $select->join('fornecedor','entrada.id_fornec=fornecedor.id_fornec','desc_forn','left');
                $select->join('produtos','entrada.id_produto=produtos.id_produto','desc_produto','left');
                $select->where(array ('id_entrada' => $id));
       });

       $row =$sql->current();

        if (!$row){
            throw new \Exception("Não foi encontrado entrada com o  id = {$id}");
        }
            return $row;
    }
```

É possível fazer tal coisa utilizando a classe TableGateway do Zend?

Comment: Algum feedback?

Comment: Nada. Estou  tentando resolver ainda.

Comment: Dei uma pesquisada e li em um tópico do Stackoverflow que a classe tablegateway é para dados de uma única tabela. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157695/zf2-database-transactions-with-updating-multiple-tables

Answer (score 1):

Tente isto:

```php
$sql = $this->tableGateway->getAdapter()
    ->createStatement(
        'UPDATE notafiscal  en
INNER  JOIN entrada e   
ON e.id_notafiscal = en.id_notafiscal
and  id_entrada=' . $idEntrada . '
SET cod_notafiscal= ' . $notaCod 
    );

$resultSet->initialize( $sql->execute() );

echo $resultSet->count();
```

Comment: Testei baseando-me no seu post, porém verifiquei que não há referência para "createStatement".

Answer (score 0):

O zf2 tem uma classe similar a essa que você está usando para fazer um select.

http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.0/classes/Zend.Db.Sql.Update.html

Comment: Como ele utilizaria essa classe? Aprofunde mais um pouco a sua resposta.

Comment: Já procurei na documentação algum exemplo de aplicação mas não encontrei nada sobre joins no update.